# How can I change my image buttons while on click to another image?

Tags: html, css, button, click

I created four .PNG's with Photoshop to act as buttons, Two images are default buttons while the other two are "post-click" buttons.
These are the default buttons I made separate Id's for:

```
    #PlayButton {
display: inline-block;
width:10%;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;

}


#AboutButton {
display: inline-block;
width:10%;
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

I put them both in a class called "Buttons"

```
<div class="Buttons">
<img src="Play Button.png" id="PlayButton">
<img src="About Button.png" id="AboutButton"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little JavaScript for the problem you have.

**This is the code for the first image (before the button is clicked):**

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>
```

**And, this is the code for the second image (after the button is clicked):**

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>
```

Reference: [JavaScript can change HTML attribute values.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_lightbulb)
Hopefully, this answer can help you with the problems you have.

Comment: The image itself is the button. But I'll see where javascript takes me.